# Facebook OpenGraph error, Call to undefined function wp_get_attachment_src()

Tags: functions, media, facebook

i have add facebook opengraph tag

now it showing error like

Call to undefined function wp_get_attachment_src()

Object at URL 'http://www.website.com' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value ': Call to undefined function wp_get_attachment_src() in on line Fatal error ...... functions.php123 ' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

using this code in header.php

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_fbimage(); ?>" />
```

in function.php

```
<?php
function get_fbimage() {
$src = wp_get_attachment_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '', '' );
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
$fbimage = $src[0];
} else {
global $post, $posts;
$fbimage = '';
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',
$post->post_content, $matches);
$fbimage = $matches [1] [0];
}
if(empty($fbimage)) {
$fbimage = "http://www.gogirlfinance.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/logo.jpg";
}
return $fbimage;
}
?>
```

Note: I am using same code/ function in other website with no issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) instead of `wp_get_attachment_src` which is not a core WordPress function